# RemoteDesktopProtocol In IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rdp

I am a beginner in iOS. My requirement is to control my iPhone from Mac or windows  using RDP. I surf in web to get sample code of it. Microsoft provide Remote desktop client Application.It can control remote windows machine through iPhone.

My Necessity  is control iPhone from Mac or Windows. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [FreeRDP](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP)

Here is [readme for iOS part](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/blob/master/docs/README.ios)